# UIWebView is not zooming more than x2

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

There are a lot of questions with zooming in UIWebView, but I could not find an answer to mine.

I've got ViewController with WebView. I load an SVG-file into this WebView, and I want to zoom in by tapping on it. Here is the code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet MyWebView *webView;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer;
    CGFloat k;
}
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"map" withExtension:@"svg"]]];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 512;
webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1;

doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
doubleTapRecognizer.enabled = YES;
[webView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

k = 1;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        k = 10;
// No one does not work correctly
        [webView.scrollView setZoomScale:k animated:YES];
//      [webView setContentScaleFactor:k];
//      [webView.scrollView setContentScaleFactor:k];
//      webView.scrollView.zoomScale = k;
//      [webView.scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(webView.bounds.origin.x, webView.bounds.origin.y, webView.bounds.size.width/k,  webView.bounds.size.height/k) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now WebView is zooming in by the tap, but only x2 and no more. What is wrong and how could I zoom it x10?

Comment: I find it very disturbing that you are calling doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; and then immediately re-initializing doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:...  There might be some side effects preserving the first setting but it smells like a bug!

Comment: yes, it is a bug of course :) and if you have noticed, allocating gesture recognizers (or any other object) in -viewDidLoad is a very bad practice, which could cause memory leaks. I was rather stupid half year ago

Comment: I thought now that we're basking under the ARC-light, we can go ahead and allocate things in all kinds of "silly" places. This is just like working in c# :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pinching ?

It's not because you've set the max zoom to be 512 or 10 that tapping twice will zoom to that level, what it means is tapping onto a small element in the web view, this will zoom in to fill the available space of the web view, regardless of the zoom value, up until the max zoom value.

So something appearing to occupy half the screen will make the zoom be x2, smaller would be more.

Comment: so what should I do? I thought, that I can zoom into vector images for as many times as I want. I need to zoom by 2 this svg image every time I've tapped the WebView